# How to get depth buffer from PUBG?

Tags: shaders, depth-buffer

I have no any experience in game development, I'm doing some research on machine learning tasks and for my project I need to know how to get depth buffer. I tried to google but haven't found relevant materials except the software Reshade where it says that they forbid accessing PUBG depth buffer because of cheating.

So if anyone can point me in the direction of how to access depth buffer will be much appreciated!

Comment: You would be better off using a single player game for your research, then you have more chance of being able to access the depth buffer.

Comment: Machine learning papers I've read that have done this have used DLL injection to intercept the rendering calls and add their own operations to save their chosen data from each frame when it's done. As ratchet freak points out, this can trip anti-cheat measures in some games, especially multiplayer titles. Does this need to be PUBG, or could another game environment serve your needs? In particular, if you can use a custom game environment of your own creation, then you're in complete control to output whatever you want without the complications of manipulating an existing game